# How to search nearby places with google API?

Tags: android

I'm trying to search nearby places but it gives nothing.
i'm using browser key for api call  and for manifest android api key

plzzz help me.

```
06-09 16:55:40.626 22228-22228/com.example.training.googlemappractice E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
06-09 16:55:40.626 22228-22228/com.example.training.googlemappractice E/Zygote: v2
06-09 16:55:40.641 22228-22228/com.example.training.googlemappractice E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
06-09 16:56:11.186 22228-22228/com.example.training.googlemappractice E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = null
06-09 16:56:11.186 22228-22228/com.example.training.googlemappractice E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@8a3456f
06-09 16:56:11.561 22228-22228/com.example.training.googlemappractice E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = null
06-09 16:56:11.561 22228-22228/com.example.training.googlemappractice E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@2391e96b
06-09 16:56:11.686 22228-22228/com.example.training.googlemappractice E/location: null
06-09 16:56:13.596 22228-23275/com.example.training.googlemappractice E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.training.googlemappractice-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-09 16:56:22.066 22228-22228/com.example.training.googlemappractice E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
06-09 16:56:22.656 22228-22228/com.example.training.googlemappractice E/url-------//: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=0.0,0.0&radius=5000&types=mosque&sensor=true&key=MY_KEY
06-09 16:56:24.031 22228-23481/com.example.training.googlemappractice E/dataStreem------: buffer(com.android.okio.GzipSource@3059bd27).inputStream()
06-09 16:56:24.031 22228-23481/com.example.training.googlemappractice E/data1----: {   "html_attributions" : [],   "results" : [],   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"}
06-09 16:56:24.031 22228-23481/com.example.training.googlemappractice E/data------: {   "html_attributions" : [],   "results" : [],   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"}
06-09 16:56:24.051 22228-22228/com.example.training.googlemappractice E/list------------: []
```

Comment: please paste logcat, have you checked is there proper internet connection on your another phone??

Comment: yes it properly work on my phone but on others doesn't

Comment: is google map is active?? i mean r u able to see loaded map?

Comment: Help us with the detailed steps that you are doing so as to guide you properly

Comment: LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            final String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

Comment: i'm using this code to get current location it works on my phone but on others doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Logcat your Places link is -

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=0.0,0.0&radius=5000&types=mosque&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyAEZ252ulUWkOIKtJw9O7JvrYz3RLp0N_c
```

Notice the location parameter - your latitude and longitude values are 0.0 and google response is also NULL. So that you are not able to see places on map. Try to debug your latitude & longitude values and also check if your Location sensor (GPS) is on/off. Hope it will help !

Comment: Enable your GPS! Then app will automatically finds your current location. and within 5 Km of radius your place category will be displayed.

Comment: I'm getting lat long from current location which returns null , i  put it manually into api its working now.

Comment: plzz send me some code sample to get current location...

Comment: You need to use FusedLocationProviderAPI for getting location. Please check - https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html  and  https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi   for reference. if worked please do accept my answer :)